# Notepad++ Curly Bracket Auto-Outdenting

Tags: notepad++

I personally think that the common practice of coding javascript like this:

```
function(){
//code
}
```

is ugly and annoying. So when I code in javascript, I like to format it like this:

```
function()
    {
    //code
    }
```

I've never had this problem with notepad++ before, but after my last install, the program feels the need to remove my tab/indent every time I try to indent my curly brackets so I have to go back and hit tab again after both are typed. Does anyone know what preference option can fix this?

I found that if I go Settings > Preferences > MISC. and then uncheck the box that says "auto-indent", the program will stop removing my indents, but it also starts me completely outdented when I start a new line.

Just to sum this all up one more time. If my previous line of code was indented 3 times, I want to still be indented 3 times when I hit enter/return. I also want it so when I go to indent my curly brackets for them to stay where I indented them and to not drop down one indent.

I've spent a lot of time googling this and haven't found out anything and I can't figure it out by flipping through the preferences. If you could help me out with this problem, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: it is a huge relief that somebody else also thinks "_that the common practice of coding javascript like this ... is ugly and annoying_" .. and also very non-intuitive for my eyes to read

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd, that's three of us now :)

Answer (score 5):

**I found a way to restore previous behaviour of Notepad++ (before 6.7 release)** which not impose K&R indenting style ;

1. Disable *Auto-Indenting* into *Misc* preferences
2. Install *NppAutoIndent* plugin
3. Set NppAutoIndent with "Previous line" option if you like Allman style, or "Block Indent" if you prefer Whitesmiths style (requested by @Shikayaru).

Nb: NppAutoIndent "Smart Indent" option apply the same default behaviour of Notepad++ since 6.7 (and related to K&R style only).

I had requested (by mail) an option to disable this new feature introduced since Notepad++ 6.7 but never receive a response. Somebody created an issue on GitHub you may support ;
https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/296